# How to use the object that I crate and use the object to recursion or iteration the next level?

Tags: recursion, three.js, tree, iteration, generator

I can use the data (like picture one) to draw the tree (the result is in picture two). 
I want to ask how to use the tree1 to generate the same tree and recursion or iteration the next level (like picture three)

[image]

```
const endPoints = [
  [   0,   0,   0],  // A
  [   2, 151,   2],  // B
  [ -62, 283,  63],  // C
  [-104, 334,  74],  // E
  [ -58, 338,  45],  // F
  [  62, 296, -58],  // D
  [  67, 403, -55],  // G
  [ 105, 365, -86],  // H
];.map(v => new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(v));
function addBranch(parent, depth, offset, tree, parentNdx = 0, childNdx = 1) {
    const start = tree[parentNdx];
    const end = tree[childNdx];
    const length = start.distanceTo(end);

    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#ff0000'});
    const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, length, 20, 1, false); 
    geometry.translate(0, length / 2, 0);
    geometry.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.z = offset;
    parent.add(mesh);
    mesh.lookAt(end);
    let ndx = childNdx + 1;
    if (depth > 1) {
      const numBranches = 2;
      for (let i = 0; i < numBranches; ++i) {
        ndx = addBranch(mesh, depth - 1, length, tree, childNdx, ndx);
      }
    }
    return ndx;
  }
  addBranch(scene, 3, 0, tree);
```

**picture two:tree1**

[image]

**picture three:**

[image]

Comment: Just fyi, those are not copies. the first tree looks like `Y` (3 parts) but all the trees after that look like `V` (2 parts). You'll have to make that first part a special case.

Comment: @gman Thank you for your comment !! I try to depict the question more clear(like picture three) .Is it also not copy?

Comment: If you don't care what the positions are first example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61950133/128511) already does this.

Comment: If I want to consider the positions, I need to draw the first three branch then draw two tree1 on the end point? If you have idea can you tell me? thank you@gman

Comment: picture 3 is not a copy. You have A'->B' overlapping C->E but there's no guarantee that A->B is the same distance ans C->E