# I try to use three.js to calculate the point after rotate and translate but the result is wrong?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to calculate the point A to H after rotate 90 degrees and rotate to direction vector CE(-42,51,11) and let the point translate to point(-62,283,63) and reduce (66/151).[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949310/i-just-know-how-to-use-for-to-draw-the-tree-but-now-i-want-to-use-recursion-to) then point A will be(-62, 283,63), point B will be(-104,334,74)

But the result point B is not the correct answer.

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work.Thank you in advance and please excause my bad english. Best regards.

```
const tree = [
    [   0,   0,   0],  // A
    [   2, 151,   2],  // B
    [ -62, 283,  63],  // C
    [  62, 296, -58],  // D 
    [-104, 334,  74],  // E
    [ -58, 338,  45],  // F
    [  67, 403, -55],  // G
    [ 105, 365, -86],  // H
  ] 

let axis = new THREE.Vector3(-42, 51, 11)
// Normalize the axis:
axis.normalize()

// Define the matrix:
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
// Define the rotation in radians:
let radians = 90 * Math.PI / 180

// Rotate the matrix:
matrix.makeRotationAxis(axis, radians)

let newTree = []
for(const vector of tree) {
  // Define the vector3:
  let vec = new THREE.Vector3(vector[0], vector[1], vector[2])
  vec.applyMatrix4(matrix)
  vec.multiplyScalar(66/151);//reduce
  let transVector = new THREE.Vector3( -62, 283, 63);//translate
  vec.add(transVector)
    newTree.push(vec.toArray()) 
}
console.log(newTree)
```

Comment: In the docs : https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.makeRotationAxis
The axis should be normalized so you should an axis describe as `Vector3(1, 0, 0)` for `x`, `Vector3(0, 1,  0)`  for `y`, etc..
To use `makeRotationAxis` you have to define a single normalized rotation axis (x, y or z) and apply the `90deg` rotation

Comment: @NephelococcygiaThank you for your answer sincerely.Can you provided more details ?